# Dimensionality of strided convolution with stride 2 and max pooling layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

This question is NOT about the benefit of strided convolution vs max pooling. This post is intended as a canonical source on how to compute the dimensionality of strided convolution and max-pooling when the **input image size is NOT the same for width and height while padding is SAME**.

**My research:** I can't find any formula that properly let's me compute the output of a convolution when image width and height are different while padding is "SAME" particularly for tensorflow. The same problem persists for strided convolution and max pooling.

I'm aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165711/8100895). But like I said previously, it doesn't work for different image sizes. I'm also aware of this [post](https://www.d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-neural-networks/padding-and-strides.html). But it doesn't answer what happens padding is same (in tensorflow).

However, let's say I have **images of size `240x320`.** And I have 2 versions of a network.

Version A:

```
from tensorflow import layers as tf
x = tf.conv2d(input_im, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME')
x = tf.conv2d(x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME')
x = tf.conv2d(x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='SAME')
```

Version B:

```
from tensorflow import layers as tf
x = tf.conv2d(input_im, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME')
x = tf.conv2d(x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='SAME')
x = tf.max_pooling(x, 2, 2, padding='SAME')
```

My question is the following. After each of the layers for version A and B, **what are the output dimensions given the above mentioned input image size?** If I was doing this in Keras, I'd simply use `model.summary()`; however, I'm using tensorflow and there's no such equivalent function. I am not able to run tensorboard on the remote machine I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the shape of the resulting tensors the following way.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_im = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 320, 240, 3])
x = tf.layers.conv2d(input_im, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME')
print('After conv1', x.shape)
x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME')
print('After conv2', x.shape)
x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='SAME')
print('After conv3', x.shape)
```